# Template Height of a gallery is not visible in powerapps

Tags: powerapps

I am following this tutorial to understand how to create Navigation menu, It requires me to set the template height of the gallery but I cant find this option anywhere. Parent.TemplateHeight is later used in the code to adjust the height of icons and options so I do need to set that value but I am not sure how to. Any suggestions on what can I do?
https://matthewdevaney.com/power-apps-navigation-menu-component/

Answer (score 2):

The name of this property is TemplateSize and you can find it in two places, top-left properties dropdown menu or right panel properties.
[image: Gallery properties]

[image: Side panel properties]

Comment: Thank you, has tempalteHeight property changed to TempalteSize? In the tutorial it specifically says TempalteHeight